# Create a measure based on a text in a columns (Dax, ssas)

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

I have a table which holds measure expressions.
like this:

```
name | expression
all   sum(column)
```

I want to create a measure that evaluates the text in the expression.
I have tried

```
calculate(selectedvalue(expression)filter(name = "all"))
```

But it gives me the "sum(column)" in the measure.
I there a way that my measure will evaluate the "sum(column)"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no dynamic code evaluation in DAX.  You'll need to create measures at design-time.

Comment: Is there maybe an elegant way to share measures between two different ssas models? I know that you can share columns pretty easily.